# Chaining WHEN clauses in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, case, teradata

Is it possible to chain WHEN clauses together in Teradata? If so, what is the best method to do so?  Is there a better alternative to chained WHEN?

I have four 0-or-1 flag fields. I want to generate a new field that is a 1 when *all four* fields are 0; and a 0 when *any of those four* fields is a 1.

My initial thought is that I'll need to have a CASE statement something like the following:

```sql
(CASE
    WHEN field1 = 0 
    AND WHEN field2 = 0
    AND WHEN field3 = 0
    AND WHEN field4 = 0
    THEN 1 ELSE 0
END) AS field5
```

When I try this, however, I get:

> [Teradata Database] [3706] Syntax error: expected something between
> the 'AND' keyword and the 'WHEN' keyword.

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible, or is there a different way to tackle the issue?

Comment: You dont need multiple WHEN's.. you have 1 WHEN per THEN

Comment: `AND WHEN` needs to be just `AND`

Comment: BTW if it is guaranteed to be 0 and 1 then `case when greatest(field1, field2, field3, field4) = 0 then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: @SalmanA GREATEST was the trick!  Want to write that up as an Answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
CASE
    WHEN field1 = 0 AND field2 = 0 AND field3 = 0 AND field4 = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS field5
```

That being said, for the given example you can simply write:

```
CASE
    WHEN GREATEST(field1, field2, field3, field4) = 0 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS field5
```